How can I move (attach) one object to another exactly without doing it manually?
I have two hexagons, I want the side of one to exactly coincide with the side of the second. Doing it with your hands is crooked and inconvenient. Is it possible to somehow move one to the other in a blender by selecting the sides of the connection. I can't find on the Internet how to do this, some of the suggestions are connections by stretching one to another, but I need to save the shapes of all the polygons. An example of what I want to achieve is manually applied



Search for snapping.

To generate many objects side by side from a single one use an array modifier

The thing you need is called "Snapping"
It was hugely improved in Blender 4.0
So I recommend you to use 4+ versions of Blender
Here is one-minute video explaining the Snapping: =link=

One thing this video is missing:
Before snap things you should choose your Snapping Mode
(it's next right to the Magnet icon on top of the screen)
Here:

If you want to snap vertices and edges – click Closest, click Vertex,
and shift+click Edge Center
In this case click is used to choose a single option, while shift+click adds/excludes another options.
Same by using click and shift+click choose things you want to be affected by snapping:
Move/Rotate/Scale
Then just snap things like it was shown in the video above.

P.S.
Since you struggle with very basic Blender things - I recommend you to learn Blender's basics first. And only after to model things in Blender.
Such approach will preserve you from TONS of suffering.
I highly recommend you a comprehensive video-course named "Complete Blender Creator" (link)
Though you can use any other course of your choice.

P.P.S.
Note that YouTube is great to enhance your Blender knowledge but not to build it from scratch.

Good luck on your Blender Journey ❤️
